# How can I use more than one setTimeOut in a single react component?

Tags: reactjs, components, settimeout, use-state

Using useState and setTimeout, I am trying to run one timer for 4 seconds, and a second one for an additional 4 seconds (totaling 8 seconds on the second one). But when I use 2 setTimeOut's in a single react control, I get a strange behavior where it appears the second setTimeout is looping itself.

I've tried:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   setReadinessCheckStatus('Checking');
}, 4000);

setTimeout(()=>{
   setReadinessCheckStatus('Checked');
}, 8000);
```

following other documentation I found on stack overflow ([Effective way to running multiple setTimeout at the same time in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606789/effective-way-to-running-multiple-settimeout-at-the-same-time-in-react-native))

```
let loop1 = setTimeout(()=>{
   setReadinessCheckStatus('Checking');
}, 4000);

let loop2 = setTimeout(()=>{
   setReadinessCheckStatus('Checked');
}, 8000);
```

and even nested loops.

```
let loop1 = setTimeout(()=>{
   setReadinessCheckStatus('Checking');

   setTimeout(()=>{
        setReadinessCheckStatus('Checked');
   }, 2000);
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should show all your component code. Did you write setTimeout in useEffect?